# Seemingly infinite stack trace in EF 4.0 and poor query performance under load

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

On a large EF 4.0 model (700+ entities), we are getting poor performance on `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet(string)`. The call to this is triggered by a query like `context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userId = 100)`.

The query performs well in general, but under load the query does not do well. We are running a 20 concurrent user load against a page that uses this query. The application for this page is under profiling mode i.e. we are using Visual Studio 2010 performance profiler while running this small load test. The profiler is using the "Sampling" mode.

The application is built with ASP.NET 4.0 / ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and is hosted on IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 server when the load test is being run.

The profiling report shows a call stack that seems "infinite" i.e. there are a lot of calls to the below lines over and over.

```
System.Data.Mapping.DefaultObjectMappingItemCollection.LoadObjectMapping
    System.Data.Mapping.DefaultObjectMappingItemCollection.LoadAssociationTypeMapping
        System.Data.Mapping.DefaultObjectMappingItemCollection.LoadObjectMapping
            System.Data.Mapping.DefaultObjectMappingItemCollection.LoadAssociationTypeMapping
```

What could be the cause for poor performance and such infinite looking call stacks?

Comment: What loading stategy are you using? If you're using eager loading, you could be loading every association into memory which is expensive.

Comment: Try to use [compiled query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx) instead and compare the result.

Comment: For the query in question, we are not using any `Include` commands and the lazy loading property is set to false. Would this cause such a problem?

Comment: @Dhwanil No the default behaviour for EF is explicit loading so if you're not using an Include you shouldn't get any problems. Have you tried profiling the database to see what SQL is being executed? Also, what strategy are you using for creating your context?

Comment: @Dave for the query in question, no SQL is getting executed in SQL Profiler. I broke the statement down to `var usrs = context.Users; var res = usrs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userId = 100)`. The performance problem being reported is in the first line itself! Also, we are creating a single context per HTTP request.

Comment: BTW, I also just tried to set `context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true` before running the statements and then re-setting it to `false` after the statements. This did not have any effect on performance.

Comment: @Dhwanil Apologies - I had thought the code was loading the objects but have realised that it's actually loading the underlying mappings used by the context to relate the entity model to the database. The metadata should be cached for all ObjectContexts within the same AppDomain (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx) so while you will get the initial hit, the data should be cached for later.

Comment: @Dave. Thanks for following up on this. I too am under the impression that the metadata should be cached at AppDomain level. Somehow I suspect that in my case it is being loaded every time. The profiling report shows "Exclusive Count" value of 14228 the same value is reported for "Inclusive Count" for `CreateObjectSet` method. If it was only getting loaded once, then I would think that the "Exclusive Count" values should be much lesser than the "Inclusive Count". Currently I am profiling a debug build - would that have any negative effect on metadata loading behavior?

Comment: @Dhwanil The debug build shouldn't make any difference here. I've done a bit of reading and it appears that you can pass the MetaDataWorkspace to the constructor on the EntityConnection. I've not tried but it sounds feasible that you could cache the metadata and pass to the constructor as required. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386898(v=vs.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.entityconnection(v=VS.90).aspx and see if that puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have any self referencing relationships in your model?

Comment: Yes we do.... but we arent explicitly using them in this case i.e. we are just trying to execute a simple query.

Comment: Can you post what your user entity looks like please? And if you are using C# you should have `context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userId == 100);`

Comment: Summarizing: You are getting poor performance while profiling. No sql code is being run on the server when performance degrades? I am going to guess that you have a locking issue in your database. Run sql profiler and let us know what it shows. Questions: Is "Users" one table? Does it have relationships to other tables? If so, are they early or late bound?

Comment: you need to share the model - at least some of it, Users, it much depends on it with around EF - EF is known to have problems, if your model structure / relations are a bit 'out of the ordinary' e.g. are you having something like user -> user (I need to 'answer' as I cannot comment)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to try is the excellent Entity Framework Profiler - has saved us many headaches in debugging performance issues like these - gives you a lot more than SQL Profiler and you can see what queries/objects are created per ObjectContext and method/source line, etc - http://efprof.com/